# Eclipse remote development

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am setting up a develop environment. The code is compile and run on the server, I will remote debug from my work station. Right now, every time I change the code I have to copy it manually to the server to compile. Are there any solutions in eclipse that allow us to import project from remote file server, then when we change the file in eclipse it will automatically copy to the remote file?

There are an option to import from Remote File System in eclipse but I don't understand how it works and when I used it I couldn't see imported project in my workspace
Code management system such as SVN and Git are also possible solution but I work alone in this project so I don't need such complex system.
Thank you

Comment: You can't remote patch every class, but simply starting the remote debug will sometimes perform a hot patch. There are commercial products like jrebel that might also help.

Comment: wel that would not be necessary, I just need something to synchronize the code in my workstation and server

Comment: What you call "synchronize the code", is actually called a *hot patch* (when using remote debug). If you really just want to "synchronize the code"; use *version control*.